How can I take a list of pairs of items (string, tuple) and add (convert) it to a dictionary?
I'm still a beginner at Python. Here is my list:
['Kaivopuisto', ('24.950292890004903', '60.155444793742276'),
 'Laivasillankatu', ('24.956347471358754', '60.160959093887129'),
 'Kapteeninpuistikko', ('24.944927399779715', '60.158189199971673'), 
 'Viiskulma', ('24.941775800312996', '60.16098589997938'), 
 'Sepankatu', ('24.93628529982675', '60.157948300373846'), 
 'Hietalahdentori', ('24.929709900391629', '60.162225100108344'), 
 'Designmuseo', ('24.945959999554361', '60.163103199952786'),
 'Vanha kirkkopuisto', ('24.939149900447603', '60.165288299815245'), 
 'Erottajan aukio', ('24.944134928883898', '60.166911666939939')]

I need to create a new dictionary with the string (name) as the key and the tuple as the value. For clarification, the string is the name of a city in Finland and the tuple is longitude and latitude for the city. I really could use some guidance please.
I tried list comprehension, I tried a for loop, I tried the update method - I can't get anything to work.

Iterate through the list in steps of 2. Use element i as the key, and i+1 as the value, in the new dictionary.

It looks like the even-numbered elements of the list are keys and the odd-numbered elements are values, right?

If you had structured this data as a list of 2-element tuples (key and value), rather than a list of alternating keys & values, you could just pass it to dict() - no further code needed.

What did you try exactly? Please don't expect us to just write all the code for you. Show us what you already know and where you're stuck.

Related: How to iterate over a list in chunks and How to convert list of key-value tuples into dictionary?

You need to iterate over your list and skip every other item so that you only grab the cities name as the key, then you can use i+1 to grab the coordinates
cities = [
    'Kaivopuisto', ('24.950292890004903', '60.155444793742276'),
    'Laivasillankatu', ('24.956347471358754', '60.160959093887129'),
    'Kapteeninpuistikko', ('24.944927399779715', '60.158189199971673'), 
    'Viiskulma', ('24.941775800312996', '60.16098589997938'), 
    'Sepankatu', ('24.93628529982675', '60.157948300373846'), 
    'Hietalahdentori', ('24.929709900391629', '60.162225100108344'), 
    'Designmuseo', ('24.945959999554361', '60.163103199952786'),
    'Vanha kirkkopuisto', ('24.939149900447603', '60.165288299815245'), 
    'Erottajan aukio', ('24.944134928883898', '60.166911666939939')
]

# Create an empty dictionary
cities_dict = {}

# Step is 2 so that we skip the coordinates and only grab the cities as the key
for i in range(0, len(cities), 2):
    name = cities[i] 
    coordinates = cities[i+1]  
    cities_dict[name] = coordinates

print(cities_dict)


one-liner solution
mydict=dict(zip(mylist[0::2], mylist[1::2]))

